# Must use <c:out> in Sun App Server 8.2?

Tags: jsp, jstl, sunone

I use `${...}` instead of `<c:out value="${...}"/>` in JSPs; in tomcat 6.0.10, it can parse it successfully. But in SunOne Application Server 8.2, it doesn't support this kind of usage

Answer (score 1):

Bare EL expressions without `c:out` were introduced with JSP 2.0, so it should work because 'Application Server 8.2 complies with the JSP 2.0 specification' ([source](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-4725/6n6rv9ssk?a=view)). Perhaps the problem is that the JSP page in question specifies version 1.1.